# Glassfish deployed project's dependency libraries

Tags: java, maven, deployment, glassfish

I'm new to Java and dependency management.

I have an EJB jar project with a few maven dependencies. When deploying the project to glassfish I get exceptions, that the classes from those dependencies are not found.
So I've added a maven plugin to copy over the dependencies from the local repository to `{glassfish_dir}/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib` every build.
I'm also using Netbeans.

Is copying over the the dependencies the proper way to go about this? Is there a better way to make dependencies work with glassfish?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make the Maven pom.xml that builds the .war declare a dependency on your EJB jar project. That way your EJB jar and any libraries that it has a dependency on, will be included in the .war file that Maven builds.

Comment: Yeah, this would work for a WAR. I have a JAR. I have since found software that enables you to include dependencies to JARs (making FatJar or UberJar) via various means.